# How, in this code, do I make another script for when the game (tsc) equals not final that it makes doesn't display those games?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

```
//credit to @Aditya from StackOverflow for helping me edit this code
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
                dataType: 'jsonp', //data in jsonp
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: 'http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'loadScoreboard', 
                success: function (data) {
                    var text = data['games'];
                    console.log(text); 
                    var str = '';  
                    var textsearch = $('#text').val(); 

                    if(textsearch!=null)
                    {
                        str = '';
                        for (var key in text)
                        { 
                            if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htv') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts'))
                            {
                                if(text[key]['htv'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                                {
                                      console.log(text[key])
                                    str= text[key]['htv']+ " vs "+ text[key]['atv']+ " score : "+ text[key]['hts']+"-"+text[key]['ats']+"\n";
                                }
                                if( text[key]['atv'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
                                str += text[key]['atv'] + " vs "+ text[key]['htv'] + " score : "+ text[key]['ats']+"-"+text[key]['hts']+"\n";
                            }
                         }
                        alert(str);
                    }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

**----**

How, in this code, do I make another script for when the game (tsc) equals not final that it makes doesn't display those games? Also with this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src='sportsscore.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="text">
        <input id="text" value="" type="text" />
        <input id="search" value="Submit" onClick="" type="submit" />
            <p>Enter the name of the team you would like to search for.</p>
            <p><b>(ie. Rangers, Ducks, Red Wings, Flyers)</p> </b>

            </div>
    </form>
    <div id="result">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**-----**

How do I make it so that instead of having an alert (please take that out) it pastes the text onto the screen a bit underneath the text already there?

@Aditya

Comment: @Aditya bumpbumpbumpbump

Comment: Your first question needs a bit clarification. What do you mean with the `tsc` ?

Comment: In the object from the API I'm pulling from there is an object tsc which is if the game ended or not. http://live.nhle.com/GameData/RegularSeasonScoreboardv3.jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question,

> How, in this code, do I make another script for when the game (tsc) equals not final that it makes doesn't display those games?

I have adjusted your code, that it accepts only games which is 'final'

```
for (var key in text)
{ 
    if(text[key].hasOwnProperty('htv') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('hts') && text[key].hasOwnProperty('tsc'))
    {
        // check for final state (tsc), if so, add string sequence
        if (text[key]['tsc'] === 'final') {
            if(text[key]['htv'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase()) != -1)
            {
                str= text[key]['htv']+ " vs "+ text[key]['atv']+ " score : "+ text[key]['hts']+"-"+text[key]['ats']+"\n";
            }
            if( text[key]['atv'].toLowerCase().indexOf(textsearch.toLowerCase())!=-1)
                str += text[key]['atv'] + " vs "+ text[key]['htv'] + " score : "+ text[key]['ats']+"-"+text[key]['hts']+"\n";
        }

    }
}
```

About the second question; if you mean to put in data in the

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

element, you can replace the next line

```
 //alert(str);
 // selecting the div
 $('#result').html('<p>' + str + '</p>');
```

It will bring your text in a paragraph in the `result`-div.

Question 3 : another colors.

For this, you need to have an introduction to CSS. Unfortunately, it cannot be explained in this small post. If you want to learn CSS, you can use [this tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/) which covers most aspects of CSS styling. Here, i'm going to make you a bit simple, just add the next one below the above code.

```
$('#result').css({'color': '#0040FF'}); // #0040FF = blue
```

For more information about the color codes, please refer to [this page](http://html-color-codes.info/) where you can pick your desired color and replace the `#0040FF` text in the above statement.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ5EP/1/) (updated, now with color + click on it to try it yourself).

Comment: in the document ( HTML ) ? No. Just ensure that the id is "result" that jQuery can find it.

Comment: So paste $('#result').html('<p>' + str + '</p>'); instead of the alert(str)?

Comment: yes. As stated in the above. Please don't forget that it displays the results in plain text (without styles).

Comment: Yes, but when I have done this nothing showed up on the screen. @KarelG

Comment: hi, i have added code for the first question, and added a [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ5EP/) where you can see that it works as intented. Please click on the 'submit' button first to see its action.

Comment: Thank You! But how do I change the color etc.

Comment: THANKS! How do I center it?